# Prove that there is a postive integer $n_0$ such that all the $z_n$ are nonzero for $n \le n_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Assume that a sequence $(z_n)$ of complex numbers converges to a nonzero limit.
Then Prove that there is a postive integer $n_0$ such that all the $z_n$ are nonzero for $n \le n_0$

I know I should use the definition that, $z_n$, is said to be convergent if, given that $z \in \Bbb{C}$ and for every $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is $N \gt 0$ so that if $n \gt N$ then $|z_n - L| \lt \epsilon$ where $ \lim_{n\to \infty} = L$ and $n \in N(\infty, N); \  n \in \Bbb{N}$. Then use the given condition that $L\ne0$, and the possibly apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: take $\epsilon<L/2$ and use triangular inequality to show what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim z_n = L \not= 0$, then $|L|>0$. From the convergence, you can find $n_0$ s.t $n\geq n_0$ means
$$
|z_n - L|< \frac{|L|}{2}
$$

But from the triangle inequality, $\big||z_n|-|L|\big|\leq |z_n - L| < \frac{|L|}{2} \to |z_n| > |L|/2 > 0$, which means that $z_n \not= 0$,for $n\geq n_0$.